How to visualize GAM fit with a multiple imputed dataset?
I’m working with a dataset that has missing values, and I am using multiple imputation with the mice package in R. I then fit a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) using the mgcv package on the imputed datasets. I would like to plot the overall fit of the model across all imputations, but I’m not sure how to combine the plots from each imputed dataset.
library(mgcv)
library(mice)
library(ggplot2)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate synthetic dataset
n <- 200
data <- data.frame(
  outcome = rnorm(n),
  exposure = rnorm(n),
  covariate1 = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  covariate2 = rnorm(n, 40, 2),
  covariate3 = rnorm(n, 30, 1),
  covariate4 = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  covariate5 = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)
)
data[sample(1:n, 50), "exposure"] <- NA
data[sample(1:n, 50), "covariate1"] <- NA

# Perform multiple imputation
imp <- mice(data, m = 5, method = 'pmm', seed = 123)
model <- with(imp, gam(outcome ~ s(exposure) + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3 + covariate4 + covariate5, method = 'REML'))
# Plot
fitted_models <- model$analyses
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))  # Adjust as needed to fit all plots
for (i in 1:length(fitted_models)) {
  plot(fitted_models[[i]], shade = TRUE, rug = TRUE, residuals = TRUE, pch = 1, cex = 1, main = paste("Imputation", i))
}

This does not appear to be a solution
# pooled.fit <- pool(model)
# plot.gam(pooled.fit)


After setting the plot parameters you can plot the models by lapply(fitted_models, plot)

Hi @Seth, thanks for that. I'm seeking to plot the overall fit?
E.g. plot the association between exposure and outcome, by estimating nonlinear effect estimates across the exposure range of values and setting other model terms at their median ?
